# Help with proposed proof of Stokes' Theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Recently I tried to prove a case of Stokes' theorem, and I was having trouble with some of the last steps. The idea is to take a bounded surface, make an extension of it, and use the divergence theorem to show that the flux of the original region is the opposite of its extension. I made a possibly wrong assumption at the end of the proof, and I wanted help to see whether or not my assumption was false.

[Here is a PDF link](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3Yu9Emj8aILbGJFa3ZMOWdteWM/edit?pli=1) of the proposed proof. Since I didn't know enough LaTeX to be able to type it out on here, I wrote it on paper and scanned it.

Thanks for taking the time to look it over!